# Terminal colors cause the prompt to jump back to the beginning of the line

Tags: shell, command-line, colors, terminal, prompt

While using git, I decided to add [.git-prompt.sh](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/completion) to my .bashrc file.  This file shows me the name of the branch that I am currently working on.
I also decided to add some color.

```
if [ -f ~/.git-prompt.sh ]; then

    #include the branch detection file
    source ~/.git-prompt.sh

    #add the current branch in yellow
    export PS1='$(__git_ps1 "[\e[38;5;220m%s\x1b[0m]")'

    #make the rest of the text in the prompt gray
    PS1+="\e[38;5;245m\w$ "

    #set colors back to default
    PS1+="\033[0m"
fi
```

Using any terminal(gnome-terminal, xterm, quake) results in the same problem. When the typed out line gets too long,

[image]

the prompt jumps back to the beginning of the line.  This is perhaps because the actual length of the colored text is much longer.

[image]

How do I get terminal colors without this hiccup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to write

```
#add the current branch in yellow
export PS1='$(__git_ps1 "[\[\e[38;5;220m\]%s\[\x1b[0m\]]")'

#make the rest of the text in the prompt gray
PS1+="\[\e[38;5;245m\]\w$ "

#set colors back to default
PS1+="\[\033[0m\]"
```

So you have `\[` and `\]` surrounding all the colour directives.

Comment: This solves my problem, as the terminal prompt moves correctly now.